# Is it possible to use function input to create a variable name?

Tags: javascript, variables, angularjs-validation

Pretty sure that my title is misleading... Oh well.
So basically, I'm trying to create a game and I have a bunch of `arrays` with names like `ItemsInG5Array`, `ItemsInB2Array` where `G5` and `B2` are nodes of the map. So, what I'm trying to do is to create a function that will give you a list of items in one specific node where the player is.

```
function options(location) 
locationPickups: while(true) {
pick = prompt("There are few items laying around.\n" + itemsInG6Array + "\nWould ou like to pick something up?");
...
```

Where  `location` is the name of the node. Is there anything simple I can put instead of `ItemsInG6Array` to make it dynamic, to make it change depending on the `location` variable.
`ItemsIn(location)Array`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical solution here is to have an object with keys, and then dynamically pick one of those keys.

```
const example = {
  itemsInG6Array: [],
  itemsInB2Array: [],
}

function options(location) {
  const key = 'itemsIn' + location + 'Array';
  const items = example[key];
  const pick = prompt("There are few items laying around.\n" + items + "\nWould ou like to pick something up?");
}
```